# How to disable autocorrect with Polymer's paper-input?

Tags: polymer

According to the [documentation for paper-input](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input), `autocorrect` is supposed to be a recognized property that defaults to `'off'`.  However, even when I explicitly set `autocorrect` to `'off'`, `autocorrect` is still active.  I can see in the actual input control (`<input is='iron-input'...`) that `autocorrect` *is* set to `'off'` (both the attribute and the property).

I'm testing on latest Chrome, with newest Polymer & paper-input.

Here's the web page I'm testing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/dev/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'></script>
        <link rel='import' href='/dev/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html'></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <paper-input autocorrect='off' label='test'></paper-input>
    </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't see any way to proceed besides asking here.  I'll appreciate any ideas!

**edit**

It seems like this isn't a problem with `<paper-input>`, or a problem with how I'm using it.  I tested on Firefox and autocorrect is disabled there, no matter how I set the `autocorrect` attribute.  I also tried a regular `<input>` element and that gave the same results.  I'll leave the question open for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's your os.  Not the element

Comment: It seems like the browser and its autocorrect configuration determines whether autocorrect is enabled, but I'd really like to enable/disable it on a per-input basis.  I agree it doesn't seem like `<paper-element>` is at fault.

Comment: You can.  you are.  The elements not doing it so its disabled at the element level.  The element can't tell your browser not to autocorrect text input